# How to use While Loop on a condition for nested array of array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following nested array `products`:

```js
products: [
    [{
        Variant: {
            variant_id: '1',
            weight: 15
        },
        Product: {
            _id: '1',
            _shop_id: '1'
        },
        quantity: 5,
        totalPrice: 600
    }],
    [{
            Variant: {
                variant_id: '2',
                weight: 20
            },
            Product: {
                _id: '2',
                _shop_id: '2'
            },
            quantity: 4,
            totalPrice: 500
        },
        {
            Variant: {
                variant_id: '5',
                weight: 25
            },
            Product: {
                _id: '3',
                _shop_id: '2'
            },
            quantity: 3,
            totalPrice: 400
        }
    ]
]
```

I have a `packages` array that needs to be filled with `package` objects. Rule: A package needs to contain products of the same `_shop_id` (got it) and the sum of products must not surpass the 30kg limit weight. In another words, i need to add a new package if the sum of `Variant.weight` surpass 30. For example, `products` array needs three packages:

```js
// Package 1 - weight: 15kg - shopId: 1
{Variant: {variant_id: '1', weight: 15}, Product: {_id: '1', _shop_id:'1'}, quantity: 5, totalPrice: 600}

// Package 2 - weight: 20kg - shopId: 2
{Variant: {variant_id: '2', weight: 20}, Product: {_id: '2', _shop_id:'2'}, quantity: 4, totalPrice: 500}

// Package 3 - Needs new package because it would be 45kg - weight: 25kg - shopId: 2
{Variant: {variant_id: '5', weight: 25}, Product: {_id: '3', _shop_id:'2'}, quantity: 3, totalPrice: 400}
```

I just need to know how many packages would be necessary to pack all of the products. The `package` object will be added after a package is full like this:

```js
export interface Package {
    weight: number;
}

export class CartComponent {

  someMethod() { 
    let packages: Package[] = [];
    let weight = 0;

    products.forEach(prod =>
      {
          while(weight < 30) {
            weight += prod.Variant.weight;
            let package = { weight: weight };
          }
          packages.push(package);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

What Am I doing wrong? I need to correctly loop the `products` array to know how many packages will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you have an array of arrays.  When you call `forEach` on the outer array, you get an inner array of products from a single shop.  Then you have to iterate over the inner array somehow.  I'd suggest using `forEach` rather than `while`.  The following is working for me in a few simple tests:

```
export class CartComponent {

  someMethod() { 
    let packages: Package[] = [];
    let weight = 0;
    let finishPackage = () => {
      packages.push({ weight: weight });
      weight = 0;
    };

    products.forEach(sameShopProducts =>
      {
        sameShopProducts.forEach(prod => {
          if (weight + prod.Variant.weight > 30) {
            finishPackage();
          }
          weight += prod.Variant.weight;
        });
        // Different shops cannot share a package.
        finishPackage();
      });
    return packages;
  }

}
```